# Conexões entre Maquinas Virtuais - VMware

Tags: linux, windows, redes, vmware

tenho 2 maquinas virtuais, uma com `ubuntu server`, outra com `windows 7` , as 2 maquinas estão na mesma classe de `IP`,

```
windows - 10.10.1.3
ubuntu server - 10.10.1.2
```

as 2 maquinas se "`pingam"` so que o `windows` não tem conexão com a internet.

no `Virtual Network Editor` esta configurado como `Host-only`

esta correto minhas config??

obrigado